# BundleTransformer.Core throwing implementation exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundletransformer

I'm trying to use `BundleTransformer.Core` and `BundleTransformer.Less`, however I've run into the following exception when trying to setup MVC4 bundles using the recommended code:

> Method 'OrderFiles' in type 'BundleTransformer.Core.Orderers.NullOrderer' does not have an implementation.

That exception is thrown on registering the following:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    var cssTransformer = new CssTransformer();
    var jsTransformer = new JsTransformer();
    var nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();

    var commonStylesBundle = new Bundle("~/Bundles/CommonStyles");
    commonStylesBundle.Include("~/Styles/V3/functions.less",
                               "~/Styles/V3/helpers.less",
                               "~/Styles/V3/media-queries.less",
                               "~/Styles/V3/normalize.less",
                               "~/Styles/V3/print.less",
                               "~/Styles/V3/style.less");
    commonStylesBundle.Transforms.Add(cssTransformer);
    commonStylesBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;

    bundles.Add(commonStylesBundle);
}
```

I have tried both the latest versions of `BundleTransformer.Core` and the immediate prior version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have installed preview version of the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework ([1.1.0 Alpha1](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.1.0-alpha1) or [1.1.0 Beta1](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.1.0-Beta1)). At the moment, the Bundle Transformer supports only RTM-version of the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework (version [1.0.0](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.0.0)). I recommend that you roll back to RTM-version.

Comment: In the [Bundle Transformer 1.7.0 Beta 1](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/releases/view/103708) was added support of the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.1.0 Beta 1.